# Apply Intermediate check to parent if all child nodes are not checked in Tree view WPF C#

Tags: wpf, checkbox, triggers, treeview

I have a 3 level node Tree View Model:
--Parent
--SubParent
--Child
and all the nodes have a check box so I want to achieve the functionality of intermidiate check, if one child is unchecked then subparent and parent would have a intermidiate check and same for all.

I want to achieve this using triggers.

Comment: What does your TreeViewModel object look like? What is a sub-parent? Some C# code of it would be helpful to answer your question. Usually hierarchical object models track only child and parent instances; then climb or descend the hiearchy to get levels beyond the child/parent.